# maven plugin jacoco: Coverage checks have not been met. See log for details

Tags: java, maven, teamcity, jacoco-maven-plugin

I understand that if we set

```
<jacoco.skip.exec>true</jacoco.skip.exec>
```

in pom.xml, it might skip the skip the jacoco checking. However, in my case the tests are conducted on TeamCity, on which we have no control of the environment configuration, therefore it might be that the above flag is not set. As a result, it shows:

```
Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.8:check (verify) on project xxxx: Coverage checks have not been met. See log for details.
```

on the failure of two tests which I decorated with annotation @Ignore

I thought those two tests were skipped but the integration test failed because jacoco still picked them up.

How can I do from the code level to disable jacoco checking?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the goal from pom.xml, it will no longer require the check:

Remove this line inside of your Jacoco plugin in the pom.xml file.
`<goal>check</goal>`